# Determine if vertices lie inside of a set of vertices

Tags: python, vertex

How can I determine whether one graph lies within another?

My algorithm works on the following matrix:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((9,9))
    for i in np.arange(1,8):
        for j in np.arange(1,8):
            A[i,j] = 1
    for i in np.arange(2,4):
        for j in np.arange(2,4):
            A[i,j] = 2
    print(A)
```

yields the matrix:

```
[[-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]]
```

To create two graphs:

[image]

With vertices:

```
V1 = [[(2.0, 1.333333), (1.333333, 3.0), (1.333333, 2.0), (2.0, 3.666667), (3.0, 3.666667), (3.666667, 3.0), (3.666667, 2.0), (3.0, 1.333333)]]
V2 = [[(1.0, 0.5), (0.5, 2.0), (0.5, 1.0), (0.5, 3.0), (0.5, 4.0), (0.5, 5.0), (0.5, 6.0), (0.5, 7.0), (1.0, 7.5), (2.0, 7.5), (3.0, 7.5), (4.0, 7.5), (5.0, 7.5), (6.0, 7.5), (7.0, 7.5), (7.5, 7.0), (7.5, 6.0), (7.5, 5.0), (7.5, 4.0), (7.5, 3.0), (7.5, 2.0), (7.5, 1.0), (7.0, 0.5), (6.0, 0.5), (5.0, 0.5), (4.0, 0.5), (3.0, 0.5), (2.0, 0.5)]]
```

And edge lists:

```
e1 = [[[1.333333, 2.0], [2.0, 1.333333]], [[1.333333, 3.0], [1.333333, 2.0]], [[2.0, 3.666667], [1.333333, 3.0]], [[2.0, 1.333333], [3.0, 1.333333]], [[2.0, 3.666667], [3.0, 3.666667]], [[3.0, 1.333333], [3.666667, 2.0]], [[3.666667, 3.0], [3.666667, 2.0]], [[3.0, 3.666667], [3.666667, 3.0]]]
e2 = [[[0.5, 1.0], [1.0, 0.5]], [[0.5, 2.0], [0.5, 1.0]], [[0.5, 3.0], [0.5, 2.0]], [[0.5, 4.0], [0.5, 3.0]], [[0.5, 5.0], [0.5, 4.0]], [[0.5, 6.0], [0.5, 5.0]], [[0.5, 7.0], [0.5, 6.0]], [[1.0, 7.5], [0.5, 7.0]], [[1.0, 0.5], [2.0, 0.5]], [[1.0, 7.5], [2.0, 7.5]], [[2.0, 0.5], [3.0, 0.5]], [[2.0, 7.5], [3.0, 7.5]], [[3.0, 0.5], [4.0, 0.5]], [[3.0, 7.5], [4.0, 7.5]], [[4.0, 0.5], [5.0, 0.5]], [[4.0, 7.5], [5.0, 7.5]], [[5.0, 0.5], [6.0, 0.5]], [[5.0, 7.5], [6.0, 7.5]], [[6.0, 0.5], [7.0, 0.5]], [[6.0, 7.5], [7.0, 7.5]], [[7.0, 0.5], [7.5, 1.0]], [[7.5, 2.0], [7.5, 1.0]], [[7.5, 3.0], [7.5, 2.0]], [[7.5, 4.0], [7.5, 3.0]], [[7.5, 5.0], [7.5, 4.0]], [[7.5, 6.0], [7.5, 5.0]], [[7.5, 7.0], [7.5, 
6.0]], [[7.0, 7.5], [7.5, 7.0]]]
```

Comment: What would be the result if the first graph consisted of the vertices (0, 0), (0, 8), (8, 0)? Would it matter which of the vertices are connected?

Comment: You have conflated two distinct definitions of "graph".  One is a network of nodes and edges -- that's what `networkx` supports.  The one your problem needs is the more common Cartesian plane definition..

Comment: You need to look up algorithms and support packages for handling shapes -- `shapely` comes to mind.  If your shapes are simple enough -- such as orthogonal rectangles -- then please repost your code per the [guideilnes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)..

Comment: Please see my edit. I will search through shapely. I think networkx does apply since I have vertices and edges. I'm new to that module and am not sure of its full utility.

Comment: One algorithm for deciding if a point is inside a polygon is to draw a line in any direction (e.g. horizontally rightwards, but any specific direction is fine) out to infinity in that direction (or, practically, to a point outside the extents of the polygon) and see how many edges of the polygon it intersects: an odd number means the point is inside the polygon. You have to do special handling when the line passes precisely through a vertex.

Comment: Fascinating. Well... That would tell me if a shape falls within another, but that wouldn't necessarily pair those two shapes together. Huh... I'm a beginner and that sounds beyond me. But perhaps that is a limitation of imagination.

Comment: Could this be reopened because of my edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prune suggests, the `shapely` package has what you need. While your line loops can be thought of as a graph, it's more useful to consider them as polygons embedded in the 2D plane.

By creating `Polygon` objects from your points and edge segments, you can use the `contains` method that all `shapely` objects have to test if one is inside the other.

You'll need to sort the edge segments into order. Clockwise or anti-clockwise probably doesn't matter as `shapely` likely detects inside and outside by constructing a point at infinity and ensuring that is 'outside'.

Here's a full example with the orignal pair of squares from your post:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (0,8), (8,8), (8,0)])
p2 = Polygon([(2,2), (2,4), (4,4), (4,2)])

print(p1.contains(p2))
```

Documentation for the `Polygon` object is at https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#Polygon

and for the `contains` method at https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.contains